# preg_replace convert 1,000,000 to the word 1 Million

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to convert all numbers with 6 digits to the word million. like 1,000,000 to 1 million

```
<?php
$string = '125,234,593';
$pattern  = '/(.+?)\,(.+?),(\d+)/i';
$replacement = '$1 Million';

echo preg_replace($pattern , $replacement, $string);
?>
```

this outputs **1 Million**

but if the number is 11,125,234,593 php outputs **11 Million,593**

how can I solve the problem?

Comment: That is 11 Billion not million (9 zeros) 11,125,234,593 = eleven billion, one hundred and fourty-seven million, four hundred and eighty-three thousand, six hundred and fourty-seven ..... ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
$pattern  = '/,\d{3},\d{3}$/i';
$replacement = ' Million';
```

Comment: cool, what sould I do to output Billion? If it´s 12,234,234 it will output 12 Million and on 12,233,423,344 12 Billion?

Comment: @celebo Your question was about 'Million' ,there is nowhere mentioned about higher values, so I have provided that answer.

Comment: How could this be extended to display values in Thousands and Billions

Answer (score 0):

I have created a php class for converting the digits to words in 3 language (English, Dari/ Persian, Pashto).

you can use it as a helper class with codeigniter and laravel frameworks.

https://github.com/mohammad-ali021/number-to-words